# Passing an arrayList multimap in PostMethod in HttpClient

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-httpclient-4.x, multimap, apache-commons-httpclient

I have the following code :

```
public static void postHttpStream(ArrayListMultimap<String, String> fcmbuildProperties){
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                PostMethod method = new PostMethod("http://requestb.in/y2d30py2");
                try {
                  int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
                  String test = fcmbuildProperties.ge
                  method.setRequestBody(fcmbuildProperties);
                  byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
                  System.out.println(new String(responseBody));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  System.err.println("Fatal error: " + e.getMessage());
                  e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                  method.releaseConnection();
                }
     }
```

fcmBuildProperties is an arrayList multi map but looks like that setRequestBody only takes a name value pair. Problem is that in my arrayList, one key can have multiple values. IS their an easy way to pass that as payload ?

Answer (score 0):

What's about serializing properties right before init a body?

```
// serialize your properties
String body = ...
method.setRequestBody(body);
```